# Passing values to methods via input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an input field like so:

```
<input type="text" @input=readInput('usernameInput')>
```

And data and method:

```
data() {
   return {
       usernameInput = false;
   };
},
readInput(form) {
    console.log(form); //usernameInput
}
```

So anytime a user enters a character in the `input` field, the `readInput` method is activated with the word 'usernameInput' passed to it.

But I am trying to do something like this:

```
readInput(form) {
    this.form = true;
}
```

Basically, when someone enters *anything* into the input field, I want `usernameInput` to change to `true`. So I want that `this.form` to really be equal to `this.usernameInput`. Is there a way I can go about accomplishing this?

Please note: this is a simple example; I am aware I can just do `this.usernameInput = true`, but I am trying to create a more general method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="usernameInput" @input="readInput($event, true)"/>
```

Now your method has access to the event, and passes true:

```
readInput(e, flag) {
    this[e.target.name] = flag
}
```

A more dynamic and generic solution for you.